# how to assign unique html id to a form field for every django form instance

Tags: django, django-forms, django-tinymce

My form is

```
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model=Answers
      fields=['answer']
      widgets ={'answer': TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30},  mce_attrs={'mode':"textareas",}),}
```

and in my view I am creating an instance of the form `answerForm=AnswerForm()`. In the template I have many instances of the answerForm inside a for loop

```
<form action="/q/answer/" method="post" style="display:none;" class="answer_form" >
{% csrf_token %}
{# {{ context.answerForm.as_p }} #}
{# <textarea id="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ context.answerForm.answer }}</textarea> #}
{{ context.answerForm.answer }}

<input type="hidden" name="q_id_a" id="q_id_a" value="{{ result.object.id }}">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

my question:

- how to instantiate django form in the view to create a unique HTML id for the field answer. Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015174/django-unique-ids-for-form-fields) the suggestion was to use auto_id. `ContactForm(auto_id='id_for_%s')` as mentioned in the django form documents modifies the id name format for all the form fields, but still I could not understand how to make django form field unique for multiple instances.
- I am facing problems because of nonunique html id that the form is generating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple instances of a form on a page, you should be using a formset, which will take care of creating unique IDs and field names for you.